# Ansible Synchronize Parallel Remote-To-Remote

Tags: deployment, parallel-processing, ansible, rsync, devops

I am trying to use Ansible-synchronize to deploy a bunch of files to multiple sets of servers at the same time. Right now we have a hand crafted sequential solution that does SCP and obviously doesn't scale very well. Since Ansible uses SSH multiplexing, I assumed this would serve my purpose. Here is representative description of my setup:

> remotefileserver.x:

```
/storage/path/to/versions/component1/versionid-1/{file1,file2,file3,dir1/file1,dir2/file1,...}
/storage/path/to/versions/component1/versionid-2/{file1,file2,file3,dir1/file1,dir2/file1,...}
/storage/path/to/versions/component2/versionid-1/{file1,file2,file3,dir1/file1,...}
/storage/path/to/versions/component3/versionid-1/{file1,file2,file3,dir1/file1,...}
...
```

> remotetargetservers:

```
target1.x
target2.x
...
target10.x
```

> ansible.cfg:

```
pipelining = True
forks = 20
```

I originally had the following playbook setup:

```html
hosts: {{ remotetargetservers }}
tasks:
    - name: deploying site-specific files
      synchronize:
        src: "{{ src_path }}"
        dest: "{{ dest_dir }}/{{ item }}"
        checksum: yes
      delegate_to: remotefileserver.x
      with_items: "{{ files_list }}"
```

This technically worked, but my speedup was just 1.25x (not much of an improvement) where as I was hoping to get *near* 'n' or at least something over 'n/2' speedup. I read somewhere that synchronize in pull mode should work better and I assumed as such since (at least theoretically) in pull mode we would delegate the responsibility of copying, to the individual target hosts => near 'n' speedup.

So I changed my playbook to the following:

```html
hosts: {{ remotetargetservers }}
tasks:
    - name: deploying site-specific files
        synchronize:
          mode: pull
          src: "rsync://remotefileserver.x/{{ src_path }}"
          dest: "{{ dest_dir }}/{{ item }}"
          checksum: yes
        delegate_to: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
        with_items: "{{ files_list }}"
```

When I run this, I get the following error:

> "..., msg": "rsync: failed to connect to remotefileserver.x: Connection refused (111)\nrsync error: error in socket IO (code 10) at clientserver.c(124) [receiver=3.0.6]\n", "rc": 10}

Elsewhere on the internet, someone suggested that I make sure that rsync daemon was running on both hosts. My system administrator won't run rsync daemon and suggested I use rsync-over-ssh feature of rsync. I have verified that, this command:

```
rsync -av remotefileserver.x:/path/to/files /my/destination
```

worked successfully from one of the target servers.

And so I tried:

```
src: "remotefileserver.x/{{ path }}"
```

and got a whole bunch of other security errors

> "POSSIBLE BREAK-IN ATTEMPT!
>   failed: No such file or directory (2)\nrsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1505) [receiver=3.0.6]\n", "rc": 23

Here are my questions:

- Is Ansible even suited for my purposes?
- Are my expectations from Ansible incorrect?
- Are my assumptions about 'synchronize' incorrect?
- Is there anything I can change in my playbook that would make push mode faster(forks = 20) or fix my pull mode setup?
- Is there a correct way to ask Ansible to pull files using rsync over ssh?
- Is there anything else I can do short of handcrafting my own custom Python based parallel file-pull solution?

(No, Chef/Puppet/Salt are not options because we wouldn't like to run agent-like-things on the target boxes)

Thank you!

Comment: you have clear that if you have 20 clients trying to synchronize from the same server, each one gets 1/20 of the server bandwidth? anyway, what is {{ src_path }}?

Comment: @GUIDO **{{ src_path }}** is a path on the _remotefileserver.x_ as mentioned in the beginning of the article. It is a file on _remotefileserver.x_ that I would like to rsync/copy to all of the targetservers. Eg., on _remotefileserver.x_, its path could be: `/storage/path/to/versions/component1/versionid-1/file1`. Thanks for looking into this!

Answer (score 0):

by forcing rsync to use ssh, you should be able to overcome this issue. 
rsync_opts: "-e ssh -p 22"

```html
hosts: {{ remotetargetservers }}
tasks:
    - name: deploying site-specific files
        synchronize:
          mode: pull
          src: "rsync://remotefileserver.x/{{ src_path }}"
          dest: "{{ dest_dir }}/{{ item }}"
          checksum: yes
          rsync_opts: "-e ssh -p 22"
        delegate_to: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
        with_items: "{{ files_list }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the SSH Key based authentication is enabled between remote nodes.

Password less login must be enabled between remote nodes. Otherwise, the synchronize task will get stuck and so does your Ansible play.